# Show Facebook likes on the website

Tags: web-development, facebook, social-media, like

I have just added the Facebook likes indicator in a website: `www.canalonesbastimar.com`. Since I have created a profile with that URL in Facebook, and I have 13 likes, I expected it would be shown those 13 in the website also, but no. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to use an iframe instead of the code you're using? Did it also fail? (you can choose this when creating the code for the like button on facebook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably added a like button that likes the current URL dynamically. This will show the likes of that particular web page as generated [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

If you want a like button, but for it to like your Facebook page instead, you'll have to enter the URL to your Facebook page in the URL field at the above Like Button page.

Otherwise you can create a widget for your Facebook page which has additional settings and allows visitors to like your Facebook page directly from this as generated [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/).

If you want this like count to coincide with your Facebook page likes, you'll need to enter your page URL (`http://www.facebook.com/pages/CANALONES-BASTIMAR/240396709325332`) as the URL in the like button generator.